# Value of optional type String? not unwrapped; did you mean to use "!" or "?"?

Tags: swift, option-type

I know there already are a lot questions about this error report in Swift, but as I'm an absolute beginner, I'd like to ask what this error means, and how I can fix it in my code?

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.nameKey) as! String

    // Because photo is an optional property of Meal, use conditional cast.
    let characterise = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.characteriseKey) as? String

    let photo = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.photoKey) as? UIImage

    let rating = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKey.ratingKey)

    // Must call designated initializer.
    self.init(name: name, characterise: characterise, photo: photo, rating: rating)
}
```

I don't know whether or not it's true, but I think something's wrong with the `characterise` parameter?

Comment: which line gives the message?  It is saying that you are assigning an optional value to a non-optional variable with unwrapping it

Comment: Optionals are such an important part in Swift that you should just watch a few tutorials on them.

Answer (score 3):

Well. Optional values can have actual value or nil. If you are giving optional to a function which do not take optional as parameter you have to unwrap it.

In general:

`func function(parameter: String)` <- Do not take optional

`func function(parameter: String?)` <- Take optional

If you are sure that it will never be nil just add `!` to force unwrap.

`self.init(name: name, characterise: characterise!, photo: photo, rating: rating)`

If not either add `?` or make conditional unwrap with `if let` or `guard let` syntax like:

```
if let characterise = characterise {
 self.init(name: name, characterise: characterise, photo: photo, rating: rating) }
```

Anyway I strongly recommend reading thing or two further about optionals.